# How to change the styleurls link after pressing a button and keep it that way

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, scss-lint

I am working on an `angular 2` project and am trying to include a setting themes. I have created 3 `component.scss` file `red.component.scss`, `yellow.component.scss` and `blue.component.scss`. I want to make it so that as per the user input from a button the `styleURLS` in the component.ts file changes with the selected color related `scss` file url. Is it possible and how? or are there any other effective and easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use property binding

my solution

```
//// in css file

.red {
    color: red;
}

.yellow {
    color: yellow;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.green {
    color: green;
}

/// in html

<div [class.red]="isRed" [class.yellow]="isYellow" [class.blue]="isblue" [class.green]="isGreen"  ></div>

//// and isRed, isBlue ... are boolean in ts file
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can include multiple stylesheets in styleUrls property. 
>   You cannot add dynamic property in styleUrl.

**You can achieve this by many ways.**

### Style Binding

```
<div [ngStyle]="setStyle()">
  LOREM IPSUM
</div>

<button (click)="changeColorCode('#9FD068')">#9FD068 </button>
<button (click)="changeColorCode('#0C66A1')">#0C66A1 </button>
<button (click)="changeColorCode('#fff000')">#fff000 </button>


  selectedColor: any = '';
  changeColorCode(colorCode: string) {
   this.selectedColor = colorCode;
  }

  setStyle() {
    return {
      'color': this.selectedColor
    };
  }
```

### Class Binding

```
<div [ngClass]="setClass()" #divRef>
  LOREM IPSUM
</div>
<button (click)="changeClass('red')">Red </button>
<button (click)="changeClass('green')">Green </button>
<button (click)="changeClass('blue')">Blue </button>


  selectedClass: string = '';
  changeClass(className: string) {
    this.selectedClass = className;

  }
  setClass() {
    return [this.selectedClass];
  }

  changeColorCode(colorCode: string) {
    this.selectedColor = colorCode;

  }
```